# How to break if loop in java

Tags: java, loops, selenium, break

I tried putting the break after clicking an element, but after clicking the element it tries to iterate again

```
for (int i = 1; i < tableSize; i++) {       
        final List<WebElement> columnElements = tableRows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for(WebElement columnElement : columnElements) {
            if(columnElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(alias)) {

                findElement(By.xpath(button.replace("{rowValue}", String.valueOf(i)))).click(); 
                findElement(By.xpath(("//tr[{rowValue}]" + text).replace("{rowValue}", String.valueOf(i)))).click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahy help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to break both loops?

Comment: I just want to click on the element and then come out of the entire loop. shouldnt do any operation

Comment: "If loop", really? ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you write `break` like you have you are only breaking the most local loop (which in this case is `for(WebElement columnElement : columnElements)`):

If you set a loop name for the external loop like

```
 loopName:
 for (int i = 1; i < tableSize; i++) {
 ....
```

Then you can break it as shown in the code below:

```
loopName:
for (int i = 1; i < tableSize; i++) {       
    final List<WebElement> columnElements = tableRows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement columnElement : columnElements) {
        if(columnElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(alias)) {

            findElement(By.xpath(button.replace("{rowValue}", String.valueOf(i)))).click(); 
            findElement(By.xpath(("//tr[{rowValue}]" + text).replace("{rowValue}", String.valueOf(i)))).click();
            break loopName;
        }
    }
}
```

This will take you out of both loops, which seems like what you are asking for.

Comment: @pals make sure to accept an answer as it could help others in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use label to break from outer loop:

```
outerloop:
for (int i = 1; i < tableSize; i++) {  
    ....
    ....
    for (... another loop ...) {
        .....
        .....
        break outerloop:
    }
}
```